# Build project in 2017 Visual Studio from the command line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio my project builds without any problem, but from command line I get the error "Hard error". Project .net (c#)

Command line:

```
 psinfo = new ProcessStartInfo(DEVENVPATH, @"""c:\Projects\[--pathtoproject--].sln"" /build");
 psinfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 psinfo.UseShellExecute = false;

 Process.Start(psinfo).WaitForExit();
```

I got error "Hard error" and Visual Studio crashed.

Comment: what's the content `DEVENV`? It's confusing because instead of **Developer Enviornment** there should be `msbuild` or `csc`.

Comment: DEVENVPATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

Comment: How to build using msbuild instead of devenv? thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the **MSBuild.exe** or **csc.exe** instead of **devenv.exe**.

```
const string COMPILER = "PATH/TO/DEV/TOOLS/msbuild.exe";
// later in code
psinfo = new ProcessStartInfo(COMPILER, "PATH\TO\PROJECT\PROJECT_NAME.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release");
```

[Compiling with devenv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b20w810z.aspx) requires more parameters ( and **i think** it requires to add some informations about projects ):

```
psinfo = new ProcessStartInfo(DEVENVPATH, @"""c:\Projects\[--pathtoproject--].sln"" /build RELEASE");
```

Comment: Thanks you!! Msbuild works. How to select project to build ?

Comment: to build only single project instead of `"PATH\TO\PROJECT\PROJECT_NAME.sln` you can do `"PATH\TO\PROJECT\PROJECT_NAME.csproj`

Comment: (if select csproj:) I got error "toolset", "build with 15.0, but need 12.0", how to select build toolset ? thanks

Comment: tool set depends on the msbuild version you can check current version with developer console with `msbuild /ver` command. Basically the version is the version of VS. ( **Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0** ) is **Visual Studio 2013**

Comment: I just use Process Hacker 2 and copy command line to build project with msbuild 2017: "project.csproj  /nologo /clp:NoSummary /p:Configuration=""Release"" /p:Platform=""x86"" /v:m /t:Rebuild" and now works without error, thanks!

Comment: Just call msbuild from a developer command prompt. msbuild will be on the path. msbuild will not be on the path for a regular command prompt.

Comment: @MichaelBraude msbuild ( as everything else ) is available from command line and developer console ( since it is just a file ). But Developer Command Prompt has simple shortcut ( variable ) to execute msbuild with a simple name command.

Comment: @m.ragalski, what I mean is that it's not on the PATH any more. You need to specify the directly where it lives or modify your env variables manually.

Comment: fyi, path to mbsbuild.exe installed along VS2017 Communiity is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\`